# High frequency noise from fuel pump persists after replacement, what could it be?

Tags: noise, volvo, fuel-pump, s60

So recently I've been noticing a high frequency noise coming from the rear right side of my Volvo where the fuel pump is located. I took it to a mechanic where they agreed that the noise was indeed from the fuel pump and replaced it.

The sound is however still present and i cannot figure out what might be causing it, the mechanic did however tell me that this sound is considered a "normal working noise" which I have a hard time accepting due to how loud it actually is.

The noise is noticable from quite a distance and it penetrates the cabin which drives me nuts sometimes..

What could it be?

Here's a recording taken from the rear right wheel well:
https://1drv.ms/v/s!Arbsk_KLR21RxA1Qlzn6wzh6vjEV?e=jmlIYm

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I believe I hear the noise you're talking about, that doesn't come through as either loud or annoying to me ... does it sound worse in person? To me it just sounds like a running fuel pump, then listening to the video I had to watch/listen to it twice to really pull out the noise I believe you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks! It might be harder to hear depending on what device you are on, but its a high frenquency noise very similar to tinitus. I did find another video of a guy having the same noise but not as loud as mine, check it out and see if you can hear it better there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=piTss8aH470

Comment: Maybe the pump is working harder than it should be.  You could check the fuel filter and maybe also the fuel pressure regulator and fuel lines for kinks.

Comment: I can definitely hear the noise. Extremely high pitched ..similar to the perceived sound some people might get if they stand up too fast/abruptly, or however that works. Did you use an OEM fuel pump?? (Or more importantly, since the shop replaced it, are you 100% sure *THEY* used an OEM fuel pump??) I can imagine that might be an awkward question to ask them, but if you're having an unexpected result from a new fuel pump, my first thought is that it's quite possibly non-OEM.